# Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) in Spring MVC and Hibernate with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate

I've a big problem. I can't identify because the console doesn't mark me any errors. Someone help me?. Sorry for the bad English, I'm from Argentina.

My code is the next:

**Entity Model**

```
@Table(name="t_modelo")
@Entity
public class Modelo implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7749256871335265466L;


@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;


private String nombre;


@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="marca_id")
private Marca marca;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Modelo(){
}

public Modelo(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Modelo(String nombre, Marca marca) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.marca = marca;
}
    //get and set
```

**Entity Marca**

```
@Table(name="t_marca")
@Entity
public class Marca implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6269847252777597617L;


@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;


private String nombre;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="marca", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Modelo>modelos;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Marca(){
}

public Marca(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Marca(String nombre, List<Modelo>modelos) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.modelos = modelos;
}

//GET AND SET
```

**Code AJAX**

```
$.ajax({

                type: 'POST',

                url: contexPath+'/loadModelos.htm',

                dataType: 'json',

                data: {marca : marca},

                succes: function(data){

                    alert("gg");


                },//fin succes

                error: function(jqXHR, estado, error){

                    alert("Error: "+error+"\nEstado: "+estado);
                }

            });
```

**Controller**

This controller receives the id(Marca) and searches for models according to the ID (Marca)

```
@Controller
public class AjaxController {

@Autowired
private ModeloBusiness modeloBusiness;


@RequestMapping(value="/loadModelos", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Modelo>  getModelosFindByMarca(@RequestParam(value="marca", required=true) Long id){


    List<Modelo>modelos = modeloBusiness.findByMarca(id);
    return modelos; 
}
```

}

**Servlet-context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven/>

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="*"/>

<view-controller path="/" view-name="inicio" />
```

**root-context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<!-- Session Factory HIBERNATE -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Data Source - HIBERNATE -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tesis2" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>


<!-- Drives transactions using Hibernate APIs when requested -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Translates Hibernate exceptions to Spring Data Access Exceptions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Hibernate -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please someone help me I'm 1 week with this problem!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have an infinite loop trying to serialize your hibernate entity, because your Modelo class has a field of type Marca, witch references again a Modelo and so on..
Your controller tries to serialize your list but in my experience many serializer can't handle cross referenced object (at last gson and jackson both fail).

Try returnig a dto without this cross reference (for example, dont inizialize your `private List<Modelo>modelos`)